# Measure TTS execution time in Javascript (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text-to-speech

I can't seem to find anything about this, so forgive me if this has been said before. However, I feel as if it is unique.

I have a program that has a list of `locations`. Within each `location`, is contained a `name`, `coordinates`, `description`, and `time`.

Name and Coordinates are irrelevant for this. The Description is the description of whatever is at the coordinates. This is manually entered and handled in the code elsewhere. The time, however, is the length the 'robot' (something not within the scope of this project) will take to read out the description.

This would be using a Text-to-speed TTS service. How would I get `time` to automatically be calculated, based on how long `description` takes to read.

*Note it doesn't need to be actually read aloud in the software, only be timed.*

Example:

> This article dates back to 2142, when aliens were first discovered.

The software calculates this to take 10 seconds.

> Aliens are now extinct.

The software calculates this to 3 seconds.

Is there a way to do this? I could use something like Google TTS or something to have the system 'read' it, and then return once done, is there a 'done'? or is that executed and then just left to play.

Forgive me if this is an obvious thing, I'm new to react, which is what I'm working in.

Comment: do you want the text to be read or not? If not then a simple math equation to make an estimate would prob suffice.